# Как сделать переназначение порта и/или IP-адреса

Tags: c++, сокет, chat, mfc

Делаю чат на MFC. Описал функцию привязки нового порта. При попытке выполнения, функцией WSAGetLastError возвращается ошибка 10047 (Семейство адресов не поддерживается семейством протоколов).

```
void changePort(CIHopeItsChatDlg* pDlg) {
    closesocket(NP->udpSocket);
    NP->udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    int len = sizeof(sockAddr);
    getsockname(NP->udpSocket, (sockaddr*)&sockAddr, &len);
    UINT newPort = pDlg->GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT5);
    newPort = htons(newPort);
    sockAddr.sin_port = newPort;

    if (bind(NP->udpSocket, (sockaddr*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
        CString errorMessage;
        errorMessage.Format(_T("Error binding socket: %d"), errorCode);
        pDlg->MessageBoxW(errorMessage, L"ERROR BIND", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    };
}
```

Запрашиваю поддержку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что возвращает `getsockname` и зачем он используется? Можно вызвать `bind` так:

```
sockaddr_in sockAddr{};
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(newPort);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if (bind(NP->udpSocket, (sockaddr*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    // ...
}
```